# nhibernate select crossjoin with same table

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have simple sql that I want to workout in nhibernate query:

```
select distinct sel.* from 
v_groups sel
inner join v_groups restr on sel.Nr = restr.Nr
Where restr.ID in (1,2,3)
```

EDIT: this can be rewritten with subquery:

```
select distinct sel.* from 
v_groups sel
Where 
    sel.Nr in (select restr.Nr from v_groups restr where restr.ID in (1,2,3))
```

I managed to make this:

```
var query = voUnitWork.Session
              .QueryOver<v_groups>()
              .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.ID).IsIn(1, 2, 3)
              .OrderBy(c => c.Nr).Asc
              .List<v_groups>();
```

and I need to add `JoinAlias` but cannot find a way for it to work properly. Any hint or good tutorial for this kind of queries? What am I missing?

```
public class v_groups
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string user { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nr { get; set; } //user group number
}
```

Comment: Looks like a contrieved example which doesn't make sense because each row will match itself which is the same without the join at all. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is an easier way

Comment: I have groups of records with group number (Nr) as a column. I need all the records from each group returned if any record from that group match restrictions. Like "get names of children from classes where someone was robbed"...
Groups are small so there should not be performance hit.

Comment: @Firo, he is not joining through primary key but through a special join condition. I bet its `Nr` property is not unique in its `v_groups`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery to achieve it. Same Idea as @Frédéric but with QueryOver

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<v_groups>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(u => u.ID).IsIn(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })
    .Select(u => u.Nr);

var query = voUnitWork.Session
      .QueryOver<v_groups>()
      .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(g => g.Nr).In(subquery)
      .OrderBy(c => c.Nr).Asc
      .List<v_groups>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `NHibernate.Linq` instead of `QueryOver`, I would try:

```cs
using NHibernate.Linq;
using System.Linq;

...

var ids = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
var v_groupsQuery = voUnitWork.Session.Query<v_groups>();
var query = v_groupsQuery
    .Where(v => 
        v_groupsQuery
            .Where(g => ids.Contains(g.ID))
            .Select(g => g.Nr)
            .Distinct()
            .Contains(v.Nr))
    .ToList();
```

Sorry, I am not used to `QueryOver`. I use Linq or HQL.